# I cant find my Project Structure in My Flutter App in Android Studio and I also have a build.gradle exception : ((

Tags: android, android-studio, flutter, gradle, build.gradle

I have been working on a Flutter project with Firebase in Android Studio for over a month but now I have run into a serious error. I cannot seem to find where my File>>Project Structure has  disappeared to and I have encountered an error in my( Build.gradle file) with my Properties and GradleException.

[This is a screenshot of my Build.gradle file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8oxJU.png,)

The View of the code Errors are as follows

[Error printed in my console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A1SLW.png,)

[Error printed in my console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qWwdJ.png,)

[Screenshot of error in Settings.gradle](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e3V2g.png,)

[Cant find my Project Structure in File Drop-down Menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pn79X.png)

It all started when I was trying to embed a Youtube channel into my app. I was just working on the API and parsing the JSON data and after that I decided to run the code(There is no problem with the Youtube Codes). Unfortunately I run into this for the first time since I started this project but I have resolved it once in another project in my Project Structure but cant seem to find my Project Structure now :( .
Everything is up-to-date.
I have tried increasing my  minSdkVersion but it doesn't seem to be the problem.
The first three lines in the console displaying the error concerning the Firebase plugins aren't the issue. My codes used to run alright but they were still shown.

Answer (score 7):

**For Project Structure:**

Close Android Studio. Delete .idea directory from project directory an reopen Android Studio.

Comment: Thank you.... in fedora for create new flutter project it also doesn't have that one....

Answer (score 0):

You cannot find it in flutter project but you can find it if you open the android folder in the folder project in the Android Studio IDE, from there you can make changes as per your requirement.

Another way to do this is by opening your build.gradle file from ur flutter project and the IDE will itself give u the option to open it in the editor if u want to make any changes. Click on the said option provided by the IDE and ur project will now open as an android project and u can find the project structure option under the file option in menu.